# Changing the C, C++ and Fortran compiler for an application

Tags: cmake

I wanted to change the compiler used in a solver. There is an install script which needs to be run after downloading the solver. I tried changing the compiler name specified in the script. But while running the script, it is giving errors.

This is the install.sh script for the solver.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#unset -xo pipefail

OS="`uname`"
dir="`pwd`"/bin/FEST3D
echo $dir
case ${OS} in
  'Linux')
    OS='Linux'
    PKG_MANAGER=$( command -v yum || command -v apt-get ) || echo "Neither yum nor apt-get found"
    echo "Following package manager found: ${PKG_MANAGER}"
    echo "Meeting dependencies"
    apt=`command -v apt-get`
    yum=`command -v yum`
    if [ -n "$apt" ]; then
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get -y install mpich python3-dev python3-numpy
    elif [ -n "$yum" ]; then
      sudo yum check-update
      sudo yum -y install mpich python3-devel
      sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python3 -m pip install --user numpy
      pip install --user numpy --upgrade
    else
      echo "Err: no path to apt-get or yum" >&2;
      exit 1;
    fi
    source ~/.bashrc
    if [[ -z "${FEST3D}" ]]; then
      echo 'FEST3D variable not set. Exporting FEST3D variable to .bashrc'
      echo 'export FEST3D="'${dir}'"' >> ~/.bashrc
      export FEST3D="${dir}"
    elif [[ "${FEST3D}" == "${dir}" ]]; then
      echo 'FEST3D env variable is set to: '${FEST3D}
    else
      echo 'export FEST3D="'${dir}'"' >> ~/.bashrc
      export FEST3D="${dir}"
      echo 'FEST3D variable is set, but to different binary path'
      echo 'FEST3D env variable is being set to: '${FEST3D}
      echo 'Please remove the old export line from ~/.bashrc'
    fi
    ;;
  'FreeBSD')
    OS='FreeBSD'
    echo "Install scirpt does not suport FreeBSD"
    ;;
  'WindowsNT')
    OS='Windows'
    echo "Install scirpt does not suport Windows"
    ;;
  'Darwin') 
    OS='Mac'
    #gfortran is part of gcc
    brew install mpich numpy
    if [[ -z "${FEST3D}" ]]; then
      echo 'FEST3D variable not set. Exporting FEST3D variable to .bash_profile'
      echo 'export FEST3D="'${dir}'"' >> ~/.bash_profile
      export FEST3D="${dir}"
    elif [[ "${FEST3D}" == "${dir}" ]]; then
      echo 'FEST3D env variable is set to: '${FEST3D}
    else
      echo 'export FEST3D="'${dir}'"' >> ~/.bash_profile
      export FEST3D="${dir}"
      echo 'FEST3D variable is set, but to different binary path'
      echo 'FEST3D env variable is being set to: '${FEST3D}
      echo 'Please remove the old export line from ~/.bashrc'
    fi
    ;;
  'SunOS')
    OS='Solaris'
    ;;
  'AIX') ;;
  *) ;;
esac

# create a build folder for the out-of-source build
mkdir -p build
# switch to build directory
cd build
# run cmake; here we assume that the project's
# top-level CMakeLists.txt is located at '..'
FC=nvfortran CC=nvc CXX=nvc++ cmake ..
# once CMake has done its job we just build using make as usual
 make
# if the project uses ctest we can run the tests like this
 make test
 cd ../tests/
 make
 python3 Test.py ausm muscl sst
 cd ../
```

Running this returns cmake errors:

```bash
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not given, defaulting to RELEASE
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/SetCompileFlag.cmake:109 (MESSAGE):
  No compile flags were found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/SetFortranFlags.cmake:102 (SET_COMPILE_FLAG)
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/abel/FEST-3D/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

The SetCompileFlag.cmake file is:

```
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CheckCCompilerFlag.cmake)
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CheckCXXCompilerFlag.cmake)

FUNCTION(SET_COMPILE_FLAG FLAGVAR FLAGVAL LANG)

    # Do some up front setup if Fortran
    IF(LANG STREQUAL "Fortran")
        # Create a list of error messages from compilers
        SET(FAIL_REGEX
            "ignoring unknown option"             # Intel
            "invalid argument"                    # Intel
            "unrecognized .*option"               # GNU
            "[Uu]nknown switch"                   # Portland Group
            "ignoring unknown option"             # MSVC
            "warning D9002"                       # MSVC, any lang
            "[Uu]nknown option"                   # HP
            "[Ww]arning: [Oo]ption"               # SunPro
            "command option .* is not recognized" # XL
           )
    ENDIF(LANG STREQUAL "Fortran")

    # Make a variable holding the flags.  Filter out REQUIRED if it is there
    SET(FLAG_REQUIRED FALSE)
    SET(FLAG_FOUND FALSE)
    UNSET(FLAGLIST)
    FOREACH (var ${ARGN})
        STRING(TOUPPER "${var}" UP)
        IF(UP STREQUAL "REQUIRED")
            SET(FLAG_REQUIRED TRUE)
        ELSE()
            SET(FLAGLIST ${FLAGLIST} "${var}")
        ENDIF(UP STREQUAL "REQUIRED")
    ENDFOREACH (var ${ARGN})

    # Now, loop over each flag
    FOREACH(flag ${FLAGLIST})

        UNSET(FLAG_WORKS)
        # Check the flag for the given language
        IF(LANG STREQUAL "C")
            CHECK_C_COMPILER_FLAG("${flag}" FLAG_WORKS)
        ELSEIF(LANG STREQUAL "CXX")
            CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("${flag}" FLAG_WORKS)
        ELSEIF(LANG STREQUAL "Fortran")
            # There is no nice function to do this for FORTRAN, so we must manually
            # create a test program and check if it compiles with a given flag.
            SET(TESTFILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}")
            SET(TESTFILE "${TESTFILE}/CMakeTmp/testFortranFlags.f90")
            FILE(WRITE "${TESTFILE}"
"
program dummyprog
  i = 5
end program dummyprog
")
            TRY_COMPILE(FLAG_WORKS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${TESTFILE}
                COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${flag}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT)
            
            # Check that the output message doesn't match any errors
            FOREACH(rx ${FAIL_REGEX})
                IF("${OUTPUT}" MATCHES "${rx}")
                    SET(FLAG_WORKS FALSE)
                ENDIF("${OUTPUT}" MATCHES "${rx}")
            ENDFOREACH(rx ${FAIL_REGEX})

        ELSE()
            MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown language in SET_COMPILE_FLAGS: ${LANG}")
        ENDIF(LANG STREQUAL "C")

        # If this worked, use these flags, otherwise use other flags
        IF(FLAG_WORKS)
            # Append this flag to the end of the list that already exists
            SET(${FLAGVAR} "${FLAGVAL} ${flag}" CACHE STRING
                 "Set the ${FLAGVAR} flags" FORCE)
            SET(FLAG_FOUND TRUE)
            BREAK() # We found something that works, so exit
        ENDIF(FLAG_WORKS)

    ENDFOREACH(flag ${FLAGLIST})

    # Raise an error if no flag was found
    IF(FLAG_REQUIRED AND NOT FLAG_FOUND)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "No compile flags were found")
    ENDIF(FLAG_REQUIRED AND NOT FLAG_FOUND)

ENDFUNCTION()
```

I am not able to figure out why after changing the compiler the solver is not getting installed. It would be really helpful if someone could help me with it.

Comment: It seems like the cmakelists.txt is calling the function `SET_COMPILE_FLAG` for multiple compiler flags. This function will check if the flag is available or not and it seems like ti fails for one of the flags.
To debug the issue you can print the compiler flag inside of this function to see for which flag it fails. Then you can make a decision if you can remove that flag from the top level cmakelists.txt or not.

Comment: @hko Thank you for your response. Isn't the function trying to find at least one flag that works? If none of the flag works, it returns the error message. Since I am getting an error message, doesn't it mean none of the flags work?

Comment: That is also possible. Can you print the variables in that function? And where is that function called?